# Calling a class from another class OOP

Tags: php

I currently have a class called Connect with the following code:

```
class Connect
{
public $sqlHost='host';
public $sqlUser='user';
public $sqlPass='pass';
public $sqlDB='db';

public $db;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = new mysqli($this->sqlHost, $this->sqlUser, $this->sqlPass, $this>sqlDB);
    }
}
?>
```

I also have a class called TODO and I was wondering, how could I go about calling $db located in the Connect class from the TODO class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imagine you have have two objects called

```
$connect = new Connect();
$todo = new TODO();
```

now 1 of 3 things can happen, You can pass the $connect object into a method of $todo or if a Connect object is a member of a TODO object, or create a new connect object.

scenario 1:

```
class TODO {
    public function foo($connect){
        // You can get the db object here:
        $connect->db
    }
}

$todo->foo($connect)
```

scenario 2:

```
class TODO {
    public $connect;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->connect=new Connect(); 
    }
    public function foo(){
        //get db:
        $this->connect->db;
    }
}
$todo->foo();
```

scenario 3:

```
class TODO {
    public function foo(){
        $connect = new Connect();
        $connect->db;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want, but I think its this

`$connectInstance = new Connect();`
`$connectInstance->db...`

This way you can access the db variable in a connect object. But first, you have to instanciate the object.